# Compare output from check_output() with text in file

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to run a comparison between the output of a command called by `subprocess.check_output()`. Since I am running this on Windows I am also getting `\r\n`'s in the output (which is a good thing).

Now I want to compare that output from that command with a text file. This fails because the `open()` does not preserve the `\r`'s. Here is what I got so far:

```
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(paramList, universal_newlines=False,
                                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
    output = err.output
    errorCode = err.returncode

with open(EMCMD_INCORRECT_PARAMS, 'r') as fd_usage:
    usageLines = fd_usage.read()
    usage = True if usageLines == output else False
```

Any suggestions to preserve the `\r`'s? Thanks!

Comment: and please in the future just write: `usage = usageLines == output`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python 3, open takes an `newlines` argument to control the behaviour of the newline translator ([see the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#open)). A values of `''` for this argument disables the newline translation.

---

If you can't use python 3, file objects opened by `open` have a `newline` attribute that contains the original type of newlines, so you can use this to get the original content :

```
with open(EMCMD_INCORRECT_PARAMS, 'r') as fd_usage:
    usageLines = fd_usage.read().replace('\n', fd_usage.newline)
```

Binary mode might also be a solution if you don't like the idea of post-processing what `read` returns to get the original content of the file.

Comment: The binary mode worked as needed. Also, thanks to @SilentGhost